# Flutter CI/CD Gitlab Caching Issue

Tags: flutter, gitlab-ci

I am currently running my cicd on gitlab-runner on my own MacBook and my cicd is working fine but I am trying to cut off some time by preventing "flutter pub get" being called multiple times in different stages. I tried caching the .pub-cache folder to be used on the second stage but it fails. Below is my gitlab-ci.yml:-

```
stages:
  - static_analysis
  - build_android

Static Analysis:
  stage: static_analysis
  script:
    - flutter pub get
    - flutter analyze
  cache:
    untracked: true
    paths:
      - ~/.pub-cache
  tags:
    - flutter

Build Android:
  stage: build_android
  script:
    - cd android
    - bundle exec fastlane saving_app
  tags:
    - flutter
```

I now still have to call "flutter pub get" in my "build_android" stage for the pipeline to successfully run as the caching does not work currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runner cache can’t be used to pass artifacts between job stages. They’re meant for a use case where for example, you need to install npm dependencies and then pass the `npm_modules` directory to another stage. That definition might look like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

Build NPM Dependencies:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install # puts downloaded dependencies in ./npm_modules
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - npm_modules
    expire_in: 2 hours

Deploy App:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ls # npm_modules is here
    - ./my-deploy-script.sh
```

Artifacts are downloaded by every job in all subsequent stages after they’re created. So if we have a “package” stage between build and deploy, the npm dependencies will be downloaded in each step. We can control this with the `dependencies` keyword:

```yaml
...
Deploy App:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies: [“Build NPM Dependencies”]
  ...
```

This can also be `[]` to prevent all artifacts in a job.

You’ll need to use `artifacts` to pass your `.pub-cache` dir in other stages. So then what’s the cache used for? In our NPM Dependencies example, for every pipeline we’ll have to install dependencies regardless if our requirements have changed or not. You can make a job only run if certain files have or haven’t changed, but then our required artifact won’t exist. This is where cache comes into play:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

Build NPM Dependencies:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install # puts downloaded dependencies in ./npm_modules
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - npm_modules
    expire_in: 2 hours
  cache:
    paths:
      - .pub-cache
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}_pub-cache

Deploy App:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ls # npm_modules is here
    - ./my-deploy-script.sh
```

Now, when this jobs runs, it will check the `$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` variable which holds a branch or tag name to see if a cache exists for that key. If not, it will run the job. If yes, it will download the cached item and use it as if it were just built. This is all controlled with the `key` keyword, so you’ll have to tweak it for your needs.

You can find information on the difference between cache and artifacts here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-vs-artifacts

You can find details about using cache here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cache

And details about artifacts are here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. However, Gitlab CI only allows caching things inside the project folder so you need to reconfigure where the cache is being saved.

```
cache:
  paths:
    - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.pub-cache/

build:
  image: greycastle/flutter:2.2.3
  script:
    - export PUB_CACHE=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.pub-cache
    - export PATH="$PATH":"$PUB_CACHE/bin"
    - flutter pub get
```

See the full details here:
https://dikman.medium.com/optimising-flutter-ci-by-caching-packages-8a1d537e0b23